# Does logic app's azure service bus standard connector makes a brokered connection with service bus (or is it non-brokered)?

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues, brokeredmessage

In azure service bus queue (standard tier), any brokered connections above 1,000 are billed extra. Now, I'm using logic apps to send messages to service bus queue using service bus (standard) connector available out of the box in logic apps. Will this connector open a brokered connection with service bus (while sending messages) or a non-brokered connection?

If it opens a brokered connection by default, how can I ensure that my logic app opens a non-brokered connection with service bus while sending a message to service bus queue?

Comment: I would assume that this is not a borkered connection. More or less logic app connectors are API

Comment: But there is no clarity about this anywhere on MS websites. I need to be 100% sure because many instance of this (auto-scaling) logic app will be running in parallel, and I may end up consuming too many brokered connections leading to unwanted costs.

Comment: if yu look at the connector definition here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#creating-a-connection it says 6000 API calls per 60s so it is just an API call

Comment: But can't API be any API, HTTP API or AMQP API? AMQP API connections are considered brokered.

Comment: I think you should ask  question on msdn and pos their answer